# Compiler errors when building opencv from source on macos

Tags: macos, c++, opencv

I am trying to build OpenCV 4.1.0 on Mac by following this blog: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-macos/

Here is the command line for the preparatory cmake - which is successful:

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/git/opencv_contrib-4.1.0/modules -DPYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=python3 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/gcc-9.1/bin/g++-9.1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DBUILD_opencv_python2=False -DBUILD_opencv_python3=True -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=python3 ../
```

Then the make

```
make -j4
```

That fails with `internal compiler error`:

```
/usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/limits:1668:7: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4
 1668 |       max() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MAX__; }
      |       ^~~
```

Here is full output :

```
$    make -j4
[  1%] Built target zlib
[  4%] Built target libjpeg-turbo
[  4%] Built target libjasper
[  8%] Built target libwebp
[  8%] Built target quirc
[  9%] Built target ippiw
[  9%] Built target ittnotify
[  9%] Built target opencv_videoio_plugins
[  9%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/ade.dir/__/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/source/alloc.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/ade.dir/__/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/source/check_cycles.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/arena.cc.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.o
In file included from /git/opencv-4.1.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h:36,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.cc:31:
/usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/limits:1668:7: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4
 1668 |       max() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MAX__; }
      |       ^~~
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/arena.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 10%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/ade.dir/__/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/source/edge.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/uniform_int_dist.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/algorithm:62,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/build/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/source/alloc.cpp:12:
/usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/limits:1668:7: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4
 1668 |       max() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MAX__; }
      |       ^~~
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [modules/CMakeFiles/ade.dir/__/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/source/alloc.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/unordered_map:46,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/build/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/source/check_cycles.cpp:9:
/usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/limits:1668:7: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4
 1668 |       max() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MAX__; }
      |       ^~~
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [modules/CMakeFiles/ade.dir/__/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/source/check_cycles.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/uniform_int_dist.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/algorithm:62,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:55,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts.hpp:10,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/modules/core/test/test_precomp.hpp:7,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/build/modules/core/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/limits:1668:7: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4
 1668 |       max() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MAX__; }
      |       ^~~
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/unordered_map:46,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/build/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/include/ade/graph.hpp:15,
                 from /git/opencv-4.1.0/build/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/source/edge.cpp:12:
/usr/local/gcc-9.1/include/c++/9.1.0/limits:1668:7: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4
 1668 |       max() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MAX__; }
      |       ^~~
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [modules/CMakeFiles/ade.dir/__/3rdparty/ade/ade-0.1.1d/sources/ade/source/edge.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/CMakeFiles/ade.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Tips from anyone who has successfully built this version of `openCV` on mac (and with `opencv_contrib`) would be especially appreciated.